# emacs evil mode ctrl-[ irritating delay switching to normal mode

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

in emacs evil mode ctrl-[ puts you in normal mode.  but there is an irritating delay of about a .5 seconds.  For instance if I'm in insert mode and want to move up 2 lines I would do ctrl-[ k k but this doesn't work cause I hit the k to quickly, emacs stays in insert mode.  How can I make the transistion to normal mode instantaneous.

Comment: I don't have this delay on my Emacs (version 24.3 on Ubuntu). Can you try running `emacs -Q`, manually enabling `evil-mode`, and see if the delay is still present?

Comment: The delay is the same starting it manually from emacs -Q. I should add that I'm sshng into a server and using emacs on that server via ssh.  Maybe thats the problem.  Yep thats the problem, I don't get the delay using evil on a local emacs.  Any suggestions to make this work without delay on a remote emacs

Comment: Hrm, I supposed that could be related... If you use the `Esc` key instead of `C-[`, do you still see the delay?

Comment: Yep same response using esc versus ctrl -[

Comment: CTRL - [ was bound to evil-force-normal-state and I couldn't rebind it for some reason, my solution was to install key-chord.el and bind jj to evil-normal-state, no more delay.:)

Comment: @wat Did you get the same issue if you bound `Esc`/`C-[` to `evil-normal-state` instead of `evil-force-normal-state`? Either way, if this worked for you, could you post it as an answer and accept it? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check out: https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issue/69/delay-between-esc-or-c-and-modeswitch

For me the delay was caused by tmux and `set -s escape-time 0` fixed the issue.